(ARM assembly) how to address elements on the stack relative to the sp
How can I address elements on the stack that are not on top of it? I am talking about for instance first executing stmfd sp!, {r0-r12} and then push {lr}.  Now I want to work with the first address of the storage location of the stmfd command, so I need to subtract 112 bytes from sp.I am trying to write an interrupt handler wrapper function to make a call to a C function.
I read a tutorial about ARM assembly but did not find what I need.

Why Are Local Variables of Caller Stack Saved in Registers in Callee Stack? has some examples of unoptimized compiler output showing it using str and ldr on local variables, too.  Not a duplicate since the actual question is something else.  For basic syntax examples, look at how compilers address locals on the stack, e.g. int foo(){ volatile int x = 1, y=2;  return x+y; } https://godbolt.org/z/xj1WExqzn .

So the figure I got because I assumed the data type is 8 byte which is wrong. 8 times 14 is 112

14x 4-byte registers is 56 bytes.  ARM is a 32-bit ISA.  If you want 64-bit registers, AArch64 has x0-30, but that's a different ISA with different instructions, notably no stm / ldm, just load/store pair (ldp / stp).

Indeed, to operate on data stored on the stack you need SP-relative addressing. ARM assembly provides instructions that help with this.
For instance, ldr instruction with SP-relative addressing looks like:
ldr r0, [sp, #imm]

Now, important thing to notice is that according to the datasheet of ARM "Registers are stored on the stack in numerical order, with the lowest numbered register at the lowest address". This means that after pushing register range onto the stack, sp will point to the register with the lowest  number.
Look at the simplified example code:
movs r1, #0xab
push {r0-r2}

ldr r0, [sp, 4]

After code execution you will find the contents of r0 at the address pointed to by sp. To access r1, you have to add 4 (or 8, depending on the architecture of your CPU), as the stack grows down.
Also remember that bits are not bytes. When addressing you use bytes, so for 32-bit long registers you use 4, for 64 you use 8 etc.
